# Express middleware runs for every imported .js file, is this normal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodejs-server

so I set up a basic express app that serves a static file from a directory named public.

The public directory contains 3 files "index.html", "script1.js", "script2.js", and "script3.js". The script files are just empty .js files.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Middleware</h1>
  <script src="./script1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./script2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./script3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('middleware was ran', new Date())
  next()
})

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')))

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 3000')
})
```

Whenever I run the server.js file and visit the '/' route I get an additional "middleware was ran" output to the console for each script file that I am including. In this case my out put would be:

```
listening on port 3000
middleware was ran 2022-06-11T21:45:21.609Z
middleware was ran 2022-06-11T21:45:21.644Z
middleware was ran 2022-06-11T21:45:21.648Z
middleware was ran 2022-06-11T21:45:21.650Z
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Middleware runs on every request.  Each <script> tag is a separate request from the browser.

Comment: is there any way to limit that ?

Comment: If you don't want that then maybe middleware isn't what you're looking for.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.  Any imported file (that isn't already cached by the brower) causes a request to your server to fetch that imported JS file.  Since it appears you have your server configured to use `express.static()` to serve those files, then any middleware BEFORE your `express.static()` middleware will see those requests.

Since your `express.static()` middleware will "handle" the request and not continue further routing, any middleware after `express.static()` will not execute when a static file is served by `express.static()`.  Middleware matches and executes in the order declared until the point where a request handler (middleware or not) sends a response and stops further routing by not calling `next()`.

> is there any way to limit that ?

If you put your `express.static()` middleware first, then it will satisfy these requests for static files first and any middleware following it will not execute.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// put this first so static files are served first
// and any other middleware after this won't execute
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('middleware was ran', new Date());
  next();
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```